# Eclipse: Context Menu

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I customize the items in the context Menu "New" (Screenshot)?

I want to have there an option for "New Class", "New Package", ...

Is this realizable?

[image: Context Menu]

Comment: they are there, just click on "other" and follow the flow

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to do that. I already got a nice working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not required to switch your perspective, you can bring the same menu items in your current perspective by customizing it.

Click `Windows > Customize perspective`.

Go to **Shortcuts** tab enable the required Java element here. Similarly go to **Menu Visibility** tab, Enable the required Java items under `File > New` node.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to change the Perspective (for example, to `Java`) on the right-hand side of the IDE.

Checkout the screenshot:[image]

If you don't see on the right-hand side, you can navigate to

`Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Java`

and then you will have a different context menu.